# Passing multiple JavaScript Objects To PHP Through JQuery $.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a object **recipe** that has multiple params

This works, I passed the object thru ajax to my php

```
 $.post('addRecipe.php', recipe,  function () {});
```

And this works, php getting the params

```
function getParam($param) {
    if (!empty($_POST[$param])) {
        return $_POST[$param];
    }
    return 'UNKNOWN';
}

$name = getParam('name');
$phone = getParam('phone');
```

Now I want to pass 2 objects the **recipe** that has multiple params and **recipeID** that has 1 param

```
  $.post('editRecipe.php', {recipe: recipe, recipeID: recipeID},  function (){});
```

**how can i get it with php?**

Comment: using `$_POST['recipe']['xxxx'];` and for id `$_POST['recipeID'];`

Answer (score 0):

Just add another parameter with a different key. Pass it to the function from the post valur. Like you're already doing with recipe

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your requirements correctly you can try this

`getParam('recipe')` will return recipie object and

`getParam('recipeID')` will return recipeID